# The continuum hypothesis and the diamond principle for $\aleph_1$

Tags: lo.logic, banach-spaces

In [S. Shelah. Uncountable constructions for B.A. e.c. groups and Banach spaces. Israel J. Math. 51 (1985), 273-297], the existence of a special Banach space is proved, assuming the diamond principle for $\aleph_1$.

Is this diamond principle for $\aleph_1$ compatible with the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: I think that usually the first thing people learn about diamond is that it implies CH. Even before its consistency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jensen's diamond implies CH. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2073421/17929

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle